# The script page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, src

Why is the script below not working? The JavaScript file is in another folder and my function only works when I call it via the console.

```js
$('#myOptions').change(function() {
    var val = $("#myOptions option:selected").text();
    alert(val);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Exos">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/exos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myOptions">
        <option value='option1'>Gateway 1</option>
        <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
        <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Image of my folder:

[image]

Image of inside the js folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to select an element before it exists on the page:

```
$('#myOptions')
```

Wrap your jQuery code in a `document.ready` handler so it executes after the DOM has fully loaded:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myOptions').change(function() {
        var val = $("#myOptions option:selected").text();
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

Conversely, you could move your script elements to the bottom of the page so they are referenced after the target DOM elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Exos">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/exos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myOptions">
        <option value='option1'>Gateway 1</option>
        <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
        <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the scripts to the bottom of your `<body>` or wrap the code in [`$(document).ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.